# Combine Query and Select Database to create directory loop

Tags: loop, database, query, users, select

I have a query loop on my page that I am using which displays all users on the page with certain custom fields filled out. It's working fine however, I need to also query these users for their level of membership (created by Paid Membership Pro plugin) and only list those with a certain membership. The code snippet I have to select the database is as followed --

```
$member_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->memberships_users WHERE membership_id = '1'");
$level1users = get_users(array("include"=>$member_ids));
```

And the code Im using to create the author directory is --

```
 <?php

$blogusers = get_users (array(
        'meta_query'   => 
        array(
                'relation' => 'AND',

            array(
                'key' => 'custom_field_24'
            ),
array(
                'key' => 'custom_field_39',
'value' => 'yes'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'first_name'
            )
         )
   ));

                foreach ($blogusers as $user) :
    ?>
//my divs
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I combine these 2 codes?

Comment: Does user_id in wp_memebers_users match the user_id in the wp_users table?

Comment: @andrew I dont think so. The 1st code snippet was given to me by the developer of the Paid Membership Pro Plugin, basically the different levels (subscriptions) go by numbers. So Im looking for a way to only show members with that level, plus the custom fields in my original code. I cant use my original code cause the author says There is no user meta value storing the membership level.